# Environment Variable in Application Settings File

Tags: c#, winforms, application-settings

I'm trying to use an application settings property to populate a `TextBox` with a user's My Documents folder.  I can't seem to figure out how to use the %USERPROFILE% environment variable to get at it though.

I've tried $(USERPROFILE)\My Documents for the default value of the property, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the My Documents folder with `Environment.GetFolderPath()`.

```
using System;

string myDocuments = Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments );
```

Use `Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile` to get the user's profile folder instead.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx) link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get it from the `Environment` object

```
textBox.Text = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + @"\My Documents";
```